# Scala, Slick: How to use insert using auto generated number and byte array

Tags: scala, slick

```
object FingerprintsModel extends FingerprintDAO {
    // Fingerprint class definition
  class FingerprintsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Fingerprint](tag, "fingerprints") {
      def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
      def customerId = column[String]("customer_id", O.NotNull)
      def template_one = column[Array[Byte]]("template_one", O.NotNull)
      def template_two = column[Array[Byte]]("template_two", O.NotNull)
      def created = column[DateTime]("created", O.NotNull)
      def updated = column[Option[DateTime]]("updated")

      def * = (id, customerId, template_one, template_two) <> (Fingerprint.tupled, Fingerprint.unapply _)
      def fingerprint = foreignKey("CUSTOMER", customerId, CustomersModel.customers)(_.id)
  }
```

and this is my insert statement:

```
FingerprintsModel.fingerprints.map(fi => (fi.customerId, fi.template_one, fi.template_two, fi.created))
                .insert((id, fingerprint.template_one, fingerprint.template_two, new DateTime()))
```

Comment: I need the insert to return me the auto generated id in slick 2.0

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

There are two main modifications you need:

1. You will want a `TableQuery[FingerprintsTable]` to call `insert` (or `+=` or `++=`on); and
2. To get back the IDs inserted you need to use the `returning` method in Slick.

**Worked example**

It's hard to tell from the code you posted exactly what you have in mind. It would be helpful next time to simplify your example first.

I've assumed your model is something like this:

```
  case class Fingerprint(
    id: Long,
    customerId: String,
    template_one: Array[Byte]
  )
```

I've left out one of the byte arrays and the created and updated fields as they don't seem relevant to the question. In other words, I've simplified.

The `FingerprintTable` seems ok.  I'm ignoring the foreign key as that doesn't seem relevant. Oh, the `O.NotNull` are now deprecated (in Slick 3 at least). You can leave them off because your columns are not `Option` values.

What we need is the table query, which I'd add inside `FingerprintsModel`:

```
  lazy val fingerprints = TableQuery[FingerprintsTable]
  lazy val fingerprintsWithID = fingerprints returning fingerprints.map(_.id)
```

You could use `fingerprints` to insert data. But you've asked for the IDs back, so you want to use `fingerprintsWithID`.

Putting it all together (again, using Slick 3 here):

```
object FingerprintExample extends App {

  import FingerprintsModel._

  val testData = Seq(
    Fingerprint(0L, "Alice", Array(0x01, 0x02)),
    Fingerprint(0L, "Bob",   Array(0x03, 0x04))
  )

  // A program that will create the schema, and insert the data, returning the IDs
  val program = for {
    _   <- fingerprints.schema.create
    ids <- fingerprintsWithID ++= testData
  } yield ids

  // Run the program using an in-memory database
  val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
  val future = db.run(program)
  val result = Await.result(future, 10 seconds)
  println(s"The result is: $result")
}
```

Produces:

```
   The result is: List(1, 2)
```